# Adding multiple arguments in fscanf

Tags: c

I have tried to store multiple arguments through fscanf, although it works for

```
while(fscanf(fptr, "%s %*s %*s %*s", mod) == 1){
}
```

It does not work for the following

```
while(fscanf(fptr, "%s %s %*s %*s", mod, mod2) == 1){
}
```

Is there anything im doing wrong?

Comment: @user12908899 the return value from the `scanf` function family is the number of items successfully scanned and stored (and perhaps `0` or `EOF`).

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf()` returns the number of conversions that were successfully stored.

Hence you should compare the result of the second `fscanf()` to `2`:

```
    while (fscanf(fptr, "%s %s %*s %*s", mod, mod2) == 2) {
        ...
    }
```

Note however that the spaces are redundant and the words skipped by the `%*s` conversion specifiers may just be absent at the end of file without causing a different return value.

Note too that you should tell `fscanf` the maximum number of bytes to store into the destination arrays `mod` and `mod2` to avoid undefined behavior on unexpectedly large words in the input file:

```
    char mod[32], mod2[32];
    while (fscanf(fptr, "%31s %31s %*s %*s", mod, mod2) == 2) {
        ...
    }
```